# Counting 9's in numbers from 1 to n

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to count all 9's in numbers from 1 to n, including repeating digits such as in 99.  My code (python 3) works and returns the corrects answer for most cases except for very large numbers (like 20 digit numbers).  Could someone help and let me know how this is possible?
Thanx.

```
def count_nines(n):
count = 0
num = [i for i in str(n)]

while len(num) > 0:
    if len(num) == 1:
        if num[0] == '9':
            count += 1
    else:
        count += int(num[0]) * int(str(len(num)-1).ljust(len(num)-1, '0'))
        if num[0] == '9':
            count += int(''.join(num[1:]))+1
    num.pop(0)

return count
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What problems are you having with 20-digit+ input?

Comment: @ ewong: for random 20-didit+ numbers the returned value is wrong.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: else statement: calculates the base number (20 9's under 100, 300 under 1000, 4000 under 10000...) and adds the remaining for the remaining digits ( to the right).  Also for efficiency purposes speed is needed.

Comment: Right, I didn't get the problem you were trying to solve.

Comment: Can you give an actual input for which your code fails? And the expected output for it?

Comment: @trincot:  input:2718398309077192475, my code output:481863010307674115, expected output:4818555247307674115

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this expression:

```
int(str(len(num)-1).ljust(len(num)-1, '0'))
```

This works fine as long as `str(len(num)-1)` is one character, but when `len(num) > 10`, this is no longer the case, and then `ljust` will add fewer zeroes than needed. In fact, you always want to append `len(num)-2` zeroes. So change this expression to:

```
int(str(len(num)-1) + '0' * (len(num)-2))
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for your help.  It would've take me ages to notice that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
def count_nines(n):
count = 0
for i in range(n+1):
    if "9" in [*str(i)]:
        count = count + str(i).count('9')
return count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n= 0

for i in range (0, 101):
    if len(str(i))==1:
        if str(i) == '9':
            n+=1
    elif len(str(i))==2:
        if ((str(i)[0]) == '9' or (str(i)[1]) == '9'):
            n+=1
    elif len(str(i))==2:
        if ((str(i)[0]) == '9' and (str(i)[1]) == '9'):
            n+=2
    else:
        continue

print(n)
```

Answer (score -2):

`sum((str(i).count('9') for i in range(1, n+1)))`